# How do I return records by using chunk()?

Tags: laravel

I'm using `chunk()` to find a value from the database based on the question. But how do I return the `entityFound[]` array?

```php
$chunkRecord = $this->company()->entityValues()->chunk(5,
    function ($entityValues) use ($entityFound, $question) {
        foreach ($entityValues as $entityValue)
            if (str_contains($question, $entityValue->name))
                $entityFound[] = $entityValue->name;

        return $entityFound;
    });

//  I want to run this array and do something else.
dd($entityFound);
```

Comment: add `&` in front of  `$entityFound` in the `use` bracket like this `use (&$entityFound, $question)`, then the `$entityFound` value is getting updated.

Comment: alright thanks.. its working now